# Cleanup of AG databases on secondaries nodes

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Consider a scenario where you have an AG running across 3 nodes and your backups are being backed up locally. 
Each node have all the default jobs deployed and scheduled to run at same time. As the databases are part of the AG, backups are only being taken on the PRIMARY NODE.
After failover to a different node, the backups stored in the previous PRIMARY are not being deleted.

I thought that this could be happening since the default for the cleanup is AFTER_BACKUP and since no backups were happening on that node, the cleanup was not happening. I tried changing this to 'BEFORE_BACKUP' to no avail.

Am I missing anything obvious or is there anything I can do ?

Command running on every node

```sql
     sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d DBAAdmin -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = N'L:\Backups', @BackupType = 'FULL',@Compress='Y', @Verify = 'Y', @CleanupTime = 72, @CheckSum = 'Y', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

Thank you

Comment: You're storing backups of the primary on the primary?

Comment: Aaron makes a great point and the easiest solution is to get a shared directory away from all three servers for the backups to be pointed to. For your issue at hand, what does the command log show? Are delete statements being created? Does the SQL job maintain and clean the folder if it has not failed over? Does the checklist on this FAQ help? https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is correct but we have a robocopy to copy them into a NAS location. Unfortunately writing directly to a network share proved to cause a big slow down and was decided to backup directly to disk and then later having an async copy to the NAS.

Comment: @Shaulinator I checked the commandLog audit table and it's only deleting files for the files that are not part of the AG ( the ones that go within the folder with the node name). Cleanup is successful if it's the primary.

Comment: Is there a misstype in your post? I think you should try to change the cleanup to `BEFORE_BACKUP` as a test. You said in the post you changed it to `AFTER_BACKUP` even though that's the default, so in case that's not a misstype, try the before piece. If it's still not deleting at that point, I think it points to a limitation of the script and you may want a batch job or powershell job that runs on the server to clean up old files in those directories instead.

Comment: @Shaulinator thanks for that. It was indeed a misstype :D! I tried changing it to BEFORE_BACKUP and to no avail :(. Thanks for your time

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to delete them?  If it's no longer primary, and backups are no longer going there, it won't fill up the drive.  Next time it becomes primary it should clean them up after the first backup.

Comment: @MrTCS , long story short, the robocopy job copies everything from the backup directory that is still not yet into the NAS drive :-) . Due to space limitations we also delete old files from the NAS drive.. so you can see where this is going ... we are constantly copying the same files to the NAS since they are not deleted from the local drives :)

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Ola? I would verify you are on the latest version and test it once more with the before option just in case it has been fixed.

Comment: @Shaulinator I do have the latest version .

Comment: Why can't the robocopy job MOVE the file? Or copy then delete the source on success? This just sounds like a breakdown in basic logic in your copy to NAS job(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current design is that the stored procedure will decide if the database should be backed up. Only if the database should be backed up, it will go into the code that does the work (creates sub-directories, backup, verify, and cleanup).

It could make sense that if you are running with @CleanupMode = 'BEFORE_BACKUP', then it should delete backups, even if the database should not be backed up.

Could you create an issue for this on GitHub.

https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues

Comment: Will do Ola.  Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.